# Pod not rescheduling on drain

Tags: kubernetes

I have a K8s environment locally with 1 master and 2 worker nodes
I have a Pod running on a Master node.
Planning to perform maintenance on Master node. For this initially trying in my Staging environment to test out.
When I executed command:

```
Kubectl drain k8s-master-0 --force
```

Above command moving to Taint and deleting Pod. But not rescheduling it to available nodes in cluster.

Any idea on what I am missing here?

Comment: what do you mean by Taint? any `nodeSelector` or taints on other nodes preventing the pod from scheduling there?

Comment: How did you create the pod?

Comment: @AntonMatsiuk Yes, I mean that pods need to be rescheduled to other available nodes

Comment: @Thomas I have enabled master to accept loads

Comment: Have you used `kubectl cordon k8s-master-0` at the beginning? It will set the node as unschedulable.

Comment: @Crou I will give a try and will update you. Thank you

Comment: How did you schedule the pod? if its not a deployment it wont be rescheduled

Comment: I have done this through deployment.

Comment: When I drain by ignoring daemonsets, master node is still hosting pod.
I am using 1.18.2

Comment: What `pod` is left?  Can you show the deployment? Are you using PV in that deployment?